# How to rename large number of files using Powershell and a CSV

Tags: powershell

Ultimately, I need a solid PowerShell script that will take a folder with several hundred video files, import the existing file names into the program, lookup the new file name in a CSV, and rename it.  The old filename is simply (ie. File1.mp4, File2.mp4, etc.)  I would like to appended a date to the front of the file in the format of (YYYY-MM-DD).

For testing, I created a folder on my desktop with (10) text files, each with a unique file name.

My CSV file appears as follows:

[Image of CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSTgA.jpg)

The "newfilename" column, was created by using the Concatenate command in Excel.

```
`(=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A2, "yyyy-mm-dd")," ", B2)`
```

As much as I would just like PowerShell to handle everything, I feel using Excel for most of this might be the best way.

In my testing, everything was in one folder.  However, at work, I will have video files on one drive, and the script will have to be in a folder on my desktop.  Because I am in a corporate network, I need a special batch file to run my scripts, which is nothing new.  I just modify the script name, and away it goes!

So what commands do I need to do in order to have the script separate from the video files AND the CSV file?

Here is the code that I have so far.  Everything works when it's in one folder.

```
PS C:\Users\ceran\Desktop\Rename Project> Import-Csv -Path .\MyFileList.csv | ForEach-Object {
>> $Src = Join-Path -Path $TargetDir -ChildPath $_.filename
>> $Dst = Join-Path -Path $TargetDir -ChildPath $_.newfilename
>> Rename-Item -Path $Src -NewName $Dst
>> }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Chris

Comment: Can you rephrase the following statement, I'm not sure what you mean by it: "So what commands do I need to do in order to have the script separate from the video files AND the CSV file?"

Comment: I agree it should be rephrased for clarity. I think they are just asking how to reference things not in the current directory. @Chris, you just need to use full paths to the files (script, videos, csv). No special commands necessary unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking there.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  Yes, I was simply asking what commands do I need to add to the script in order for me to run the script from a folder, separate from the actual files that I need to rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the date column is in your Excel file and if you want to rename all files in the folder, but if that is the case, you don't need a csv file at all and can do this:

```
$sourceFolder = 'X:\Path\to\the\video\files'                 # change this to the real path
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter '*.mp4' -File |    # iterate through the files in the folder
    Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'} |  # don't rename files that already start with the date
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1}' -f $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Name } -WhatIf
```

This uses parameter `-Filter '*.mp4'`, to get only files with an .mp4 extension. For the files in your testfolder (Desktop\Rename Project), change this to `-Filter '*.txt'`.
If you want **all** files renamed, no matter what the extension, simply remove the Filter from the cmdlet.

Because of the `-WhatIf` switch, no file is actually renamed and the code just shows in the console what *would* happen. Once satisfied that this is OK, remove the `-WhatIf`

Hope that helps.

Comment: The date column is what I used to concatenate to what would become the new file name.

I know you said I wouldn't need the CSV file, but I think I still need it though unless I am missing something entirely.

I just added double-quotes to the source path.

How did it pull the actual date that the file was released?  It matches perfectly with the CSV file I had created.  Are the release dates somehow tied to the meta data of each file?

Comment: @ChrisRanes Yes, the `Get-ChildItem` collects FileInfo objects (in this case because of the `-File` switch there will be no DirectoryInfo) objects. These objects contain a lot of information about each file, including the LastWriteTime. This is the Last Modified date you see in Explorer. So that date is already there and you don't need to create an "in-between" csv file for that.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much.  This will defintely be handy going forward.

If there was a reason why I needed to use a CSV, say if the "Last Modified Date" was not included for some reason, how would you modify your script to be able to rename the files?

Comment: @ChrisRanes The LastWriteTime date is ALWAYS present. Lookup FileInfo to see all available properties. If you feel my answer solved your problem, I would be grateful if you would accept it by clicking the checkmark icon next to it.

Comment: would I need to modify any of these commands to run on Powershell 2.0?  The script as written works great with the PS built into Windows 10.  However, at work, on Windows 7, and with running the following batch file to get the script to run, I get the following error.

Comment: Batch File:
powershell.exe -noexit -nologo -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -file Rename.ps1

Error:
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.
At C:\Users\cranes\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Rename.ps1:2 char:56
+ Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter '*.mp4' -File <<<<  |    # iterate through the files in the folder
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: @ChrisRanes Yes, on PS < 3.0, the `-File` switch doesn't exist. For that, you need to remove `-File` and change the `Where-Object` to `Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -notmatch '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'}`. This also works in higher versions of PowerShell, but is more inefficient.  If possible update PowerShell, because v2 is really old..

Answer (score 0):

```
$targetdir="C:\path\to\where\our\file\directory\is"
$pathtocsv="c:\path\to\csv.csv"

Import-Csv -Path $pathtocsv | ForEach-Object {
    $Src = Join-Path -Path $TargetDir -ChildPath $_.filename
    $Dst = Join-Path -Path $TargetDir -ChildPath $_.newfilename
    Rename-Item -Path $Src -NewName $Dst
}
```

Why would this not work in any situation?

Comment: OP, is your use case narrow enough that hard-coded paths fit the need, or does it warrant a parameterized script using advanced functions or module imports?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if the csv had the columns path and newname, it could be piped directly to rename-item:

```
path,newname
file.txt,file2.txt

import-csv ren.csv | Rename-Item -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /Users/js/foo/file.txt Destination: /Users/js/foo/file2.txt".
```